# Non-trivial one dimensional representation of the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I met an interesting question asks a non-trivial one-dimensional representation of the dihedral group $D_n$.

I know since a^2 = 1 so a -> -1. However, what about $b^n$ and $abab$? It seems I have not many options on that... $b^n = 1$ simply stuck if we need it to be unique for this n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one dimension representations over $\mathbb C$ is given by $a\mapsto\alpha$ and $b\mapsto\beta$ for a pair of non-zero complex numbers $\alpha,\beta$. These need to satisfy $\alpha^2=1$, $\alpha\beta\alpha=\beta^{n-1}$ and $\beta^n=1$, but since $\alpha,\beta$ commute, the middle condition becomes $\beta=\beta^{n-1}$, and hence $\beta^2=\beta^n=1$. So we have $\alpha,\beta\in\{\pm1\}$, and $\beta^n=1$. This gives 2 possibilities if $n$ is odd, and 4 if $n$ is even.

So only if $n$ is odd is there a unique non-trivial one dimensional representation, given by $a\mapsto-1,b\mapsto1$.

Comment: If n is odd, then how can b be -1? I thought in this case b must be 1, right? Other wise b^n won't be 1.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, now fixed.

Comment: In fairness, the nontrivial 1-d rep may not be unique, but its the *obvious* one you get by composing the natural 2-d rep with the determinant map.

Comment: @AndrewHubery It seems to me that the same argument holds over $\mathbb{R}$. So is it true that one-dimensional representation over $\mathbb{R}$ for $D_n$ are 2 if n is odd and 4 if n is even?

Comment: The same holds over any field of characteristic not 2.